# Nested .git folders in a repository

Tags: git

I have created folder with name "TestAutomations" then run command like 'git status', 'git init' and later clone the code from repository to local by 'git clone url' and complete folder is clone on local with name "Test123". "Test123" folder as .git file in it and also "TestAutomations" as .git Now again run the command like 'git status' , ask to add files of "Test123". when run command "git add ." then message display to use "git submodule add url" or "git remove files..

What should I do in this case which ".git" should be deleted?

Comment: You now have a repository inside a repository. Was this intended? If you intend to clone a repository, you do not need to initialize it first. Most likely you initialized a folder, then didn't specify a target folder when cloning, so the clone command added a subfolder to your repository with the cloned repository, hence a repository inside a repository.

Comment: If you didn't intend for this to happen, and if you have not yet made any changes to any files, remove everything and only do the clone command this time. In other words, delete TestAutomations, and then clone the repository.

Comment: yes, now what to do?

Comment: If you are in doubt, don't delete anything, but do the clone command again in a new folder.

Comment: Yes, as in, this was intended? Then I guess my question would be what your question is.

Comment: I am new ti git , hence after watching video online, I created folder and later initailize it. but after cloning found that that folder is created with code and .git file inside

Comment: Try cloning again into a fresh folder.

Comment: ok, done. Is it when we create folder , git init then .git created is for the local? and after cloning what we get .git file is for the project which we have clone.

Comment: Unfortunately, I think you need to go through more tutorials, Stack Overflow comment section is not a good way to have a long term discussion and teaching session for git.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222898/discussion-between-vipin-singh-and-lasse-v-karlsen).